# .htaccess rewrite pass all query strings through

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently I use:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ page.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Which is good for when passing one querystring through.

But is there a way just to pass all querystrings through? i.e. One page request might be:

```
domain.com/contact?course=23
```

and another may be:

```
domain.com/contact?workshop=41
```

So I need to know what the query string name is, but only ever one will be passed in at a time

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can just add the [`[QSA]` (query string append) flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) to the end of your `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ page.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will process your request as you've already done, and add any further querystring params onto the end.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do.

`RewriteRule ^((/?[^/]+)+/?)$ ?q=$1 [L]`

Now the whole part after domain.com/ is in `$_GET['q']` in `index.php`. E.g. if you request `domain.com/articles/12`, `q` contains `articles/12`. It's then trivial parse it with e.g. `explode('/', $_GET['q'])`.