# How do I redirect a url with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I redirect a url with parameters
I will like to write this url:

```
http://mydomain.com/dk/silkeborg?latitude=56.1631229&longitude=9.536976500000037&zoom=14
```

and redirect it to

```
http://mydomain.com/index.php?country=dk&city=silkeborg&latitude=56.1631229&longitude=9.536976500000037&zoom=14
```

To day I use the below rule, that don't take any parameters

```
RewriteRule (dk|de)/(.*)  index.php?country=$1&city=$2 [NC]
```

Please help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess rewrite pass all query strings through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048151/htaccess-rewrite-pass-all-query-strings-through)

Comment: Look over the linked question, but the crux is that you need the `[QSA]` flag.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to use `[QSA]` because you're rewriting the query (it's enabled by default unless you rewrite the query). Here we're capturing the country code and passing it as a var. Then QSA is catching the rest of the variables and adding them to the query string.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(dk|de)/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* index.php?country=%1 [QSA,L]
```

To use your existing rule, you would append `[QSA]`

```
RewriteRule (dk|de)/(.*)  index.php?country=$1&city=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

When the page loads you can access the country via `$_GET['country']` and city via `$_GET['city']`.

Comment: I tryed this in http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/
http://cazzala.com/dk/silkeborg?latitude=56.1631229&longitude=9.536976500000037&zoom=14
RewriteRule (dk|de)/(.*)  index.php?country=$1&city=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

and it gives this output url
http://cazzala.com/index.php?country=dk&city=silkeborg

Why does it not work?

Comment: Your site/app's not configured to process the query string apparently.