# Pseudo-subdomains with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm attempting to configure what I've seen described as "Pseudo-subdomains"(a la Craigslist) using mod_rewrite so that when a user navigates to 'location.mydomain.com' it rewrites the url as 'index.php?loc=x'.

The following code works as described, my question is this: How do I rewrite these directives to handle additional parameters besides location. An example of this would look like "location.mydomain.com?user=me"

Anyway, here is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}<->%{REQUEST_URI} ^(www\.)?([^.]+).*<->/([^/]+) [NC] 
RewriteCond %2<->%3 !^(.*)<->\1$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php\?loc=%2 [L]
```

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048151/htaccess-rewrite-pass-all-query-strings-through -  generally you just need a `[QSA]` flag.

Comment: Worked flawlessly. Thanks Michael!